# Why are Cygwin's software development programs not seeing the essential dll, but every other dll?

Tags: windows, cygwin

I can't use any of Cygwin's compilers or linkers or assemblers whatsoever, giving the error that claims that `cygwin1.dll` is non-existent or not on the path...

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe -c -o main.o main.c
      0 [main] x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ (10428) C:\cygwin64\bin\x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180345408/0x180357408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
make: *** [Makefile:8: build] Error 127
```

[image: []][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8eGO.png)

I have no idea what to do at this point, I've restarted my pc about 10 times now and nothing has fixed this error.

Comment: What's happen if you put only `cygwin64\bin\` in the PATH ? What IDE are you using ? Can you compile from within the  Cygwin Terminal ?

Comment: @matzeri I am using Windows 10, therefore linux-style paths wouldn't work. there is no "/" path, so it would point to a non-existent directory, and no, i cannot use any of the cygwin executables from within the cygwin terminal I am using no IDE, I'm using very basic "hello world" c to test.

Comment: Are you running Cygwin environment from the Cygwin terminal or not ? It is not clear from your description

Comment: I am, I have done both. Sorry for not making that clear. I've tried both in short and neither works.

Comment: Can you run `cygcheck -c` and `cygcheck -s` to see is there are any errors ?

Comment: Are you running your compile from the cygwin terminal? If not, you will have to explain how you are running the compiler in detail.

Comment: @Philippe I receive an odd error: `Can't find the cygrunsrv utility, skipping services check`